# Code with Python: Should i choose a framework or go with core python to develop web? Which is the native DB for Python web?

Tags: python, web, frameworks, project

I am the student of final year can you suggest me some Python web projects?
I want to learn python and build my final year project in Python but I've no idea how to work with python so please guide me and answer my following questions please

Should i choose a framework or go with core python to develop web?
Which is the native DB for Python web? e.g MySQL is native DB for PHP.
Which Web framework of Python should choose and why?

Comment: this is really the wrong place to ask, and also how the heck did you get to your final year and only NOW made an account? [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) is pretty good for projects. the choice of sql isnt important, [python can work with any of them](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) but a popular choice for school projects is [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: There is no "native db". Not in Python, and not in PHP either. And you can't "go with core python to develop web".

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use >>> import MySQLdb
Then connect to the database with

> > > conn=MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='') 
> > >       then create a cursor for the connection >>>cursor = conn.cursor()
> > >       I am not that familiar with Python but this is what i would try. Glad to help if i did.
> > >       I have heard that Python is easier to learn and is very efficient to web developing. I would go with Core Python for web developing.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should choose a framework to work with. There are plenty to do Web Projects. Probably Django is one of the most popular ones. You have other choices like Flask or Falcon. You can work with any database, as for Django de default one is sqlite3, but is easy to change for others like postgres or MySQL.

This are some links you might find useful

https://www.djangoproject.com/start/

http://flask.pocoo.org/

https://falconframework.org/

Hope this helps.